# no me toma los campos del ajax

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, post

este es el error

> index_for_we.html:42 POST
>   http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/ 400 (Bad
>   Request) (anonymous) @ index_for_we.html:42 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
>   r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3 index_for_we.html:60 You saved this item
>   {response_key: "c23603c223032a4b4653fe49c80191f4dfa88e6a", ERROR: "Se
>   debe ingresar el nombre del contacto", VAL: "0"}

```html
<html>
<title>Titulo de la web</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prueba.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="alternate" title="Pozolería RSS" type="application/rss+xml" href="/feed.rss" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $entidad = $('#entidad');
 var order_ent = {order_ent:$entidad.val()};
 var $name = $('#name');
 var order_name = {order_name:$name.val()};
 var $cedula = $('#cedula');
 var order_cedula = {order_cedula:$cedula.val()};
 var $mail = $('#mail');
 var order_mail = {order_mail:$mail.val()};
 var $phone = $('#phone');
 var order_phone = {phone:$phone.val()};
 var $fax = $('#fax');
 var order_fax = {order_fax:$fax.val()};
 var $dir = $('#dir');
 var order_dir = {order_dir:$dir.val()};
 var $city = $('#city');
 var order_city = {order_city:$city.val()};
 var $cargo = $('#cargo');
 var order_cargo = {order_cargo:$cargo.val()};
 var $description = $('#description');
 var order_description = {order_description:$description.val()};

 console.log(order_description,order_dir,order_cargo,order_city,order_fax,order_cedula,order_mail,order_ent)
 $(document).ready(function(){   
 $('#idBoton').click( function(){   
   
    fetch('http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"auth_key": "ffa07465e5af0a0f69d776e3a288dea1", 
   order_ent: $( "entity_number"), order_cedula: $("contact_identification"),
   order_name: $( "contact_name"),
    order_mail: $("contact_email"),
    order_phone: $("contact_phone"),
    order_fax: $("contact_fax"),
    order_dir: $("contact_address"),
   order_city: $("city_name") ,
   order_cargo: $( "contact_position_name"),
    order_description: $("description" ) })
   })
    .then(response => response.json()) // response.json() returns a promise
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("You saved this item", response); //returns the new item along with its ID
    })
});
 });
 </script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="container" id="informacion">
    <form action="procesar.php" method="post" name="frm" >
       <div class="form-row">
<p id="server"></p>
    <div id="informacion">
        <ul></ul>
       <button id="clave"></button>
    </div>

<div id="informacion_2">
     <ul></ul>
<input type="number" id="entidad" value="4006">
<input type="text" id="nombre" value="valor">
<input type="number" id="cedula" value="valor">
<input type="mail" id="mail" value="valor">
<input type="number" id="phone" value="valor">
<input type="number" id="fax" value="valor">
<input type="text" id="dir" value="valor">
<input type="text" id="city" value="valor">
<input type="text" id="cargo" value="valor">
<input type="text" id="description" value="valor">

</div>
 <button type="button" id="idBoton" class="btn btn-primary" >envio</button>

</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltaron los .val() , los id.

```
$('#idBoton').click( function(){   

    fetch('http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"auth_key": "ffa07465e5af0a0f69d776e3a288dea1", 
   order_ent: $( "#entidad").val(),
 order_cedula: $("#cedula").val(),
   order_name: $( "#name").val(),
    order_mail: $("#mail").val(),
    order_phone: $("#phone").val(),
    order_fax: $("#fax").val(),
    order_dir: $("#dir").val(),
   order_city: $("#city").val(),
   order_cargo: $( "#cargo").val(),
    order_description: $("#description" ).val() })
   })
```